# Linux to windows migration, converting htaccess to web.config

Tags: web-config

I am trying to setup a php application on a windows server for a client. But my experience with windows is minimal and I am currently trying to setup the web.config file.
Below is my current htaccess on the linux server. How do I setup the web.config file and do I place this on the website root folder as as htaccess?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score -1):

So after research I found some answers and below is the file that worked for me on a zend framework application. Hope this will help someone trying to setup a zend app on a windows server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Ignore files on the filesystem" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^.*$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```